# How to get single row of records in excel file?

Tags: excel

I have list of rows in excel sheet. I want to get how many of them displaying only one time.

For Example:

```
test1
test2
test3
test3
test4
test4
```

From above list, i want to get only "test1,test2". Because these are the rows unique. How to do in excel file ?

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=1,1,"")
```

in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=1,1+MAX($B$1:B1),"")
```

and copy down. *(column **B** marks the values of interest)*

Finally in **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),B:B,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]